# RTMP streaming in Android without flash

Tags: android, rtmp

whether a RTMP stream can be played on Android without flash??

Comment: Did you get solution of this problem? i am facing this issue, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

No it cannot be played without flash because `rtmp stream` is used for flash. A flash player is required.